# Validação de intervalo de dias

Tags: javascript, react

Fala pessoal,

Estou precisando validar um intervalo dias.

Esses intervalos são compostos por dia inicial e dia final.

No meu banco eu tenho os seguintes registros:

[16,31]
[32,45]
[45,70]
[90,99]

As primeiras colunas são os dias inicias e a segunda dias finais.

A regra é a seguinte não posso ter um intervalo de dia dentro de um existente.
Exemplo: não posso ter [14,17], pois 17 entra na regra do [16,31].

Estou tentando registar o intervalo de 80 a 88 dias, mas não tá dando certo.

Tentei utilizar um for para fazer essa validação, mas sem sucesso.

Alguém poderia ajudar?